# validating Phone number in from of (xxx) xxx-xxxx using String method split only

Tags: java, string

I have to split a phone number in the format of `(xxx) xxx-xxxx`, I searched around but the solutions I found was about using regular expressions but I was asked to just use split method of class `String`. I worked it out in a small program shown below but is there a way of doing it with fewer lines of code?

```
package StringReview;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringExercise {

    static Scanner scanner = new Scanner (System.in);
    static String [] number;
    static String array[] ;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Enter a phone number: with () and -");
        String phoneNumber = scanner.nextLine();
        array = phoneNumber.split(" ");
        for(String st : array ){
            if(st.contains("-")){
                    number=cut(st);
            }else
                System.out.println(st);             
        }
        for (String str : number){
            System.out.println(str);
        }
    }

    private static String[] cut(String st) {
         return st.split("-");
    }
}
```

Comment: If someone has asked you to use String.split and not use regular expressions, you might want to point out that the argument to String.split is a regular expression.

Comment: @DonRoby thanks I didn't know.

Comment: Is it a hateful exam question? Why "*using String method split only*"?

Comment: @Lion :) No..just a book giving me a hard time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    String phoneNumber = "(123)456-7890";
    String[] parts = phoneNumber.split("\\D+");
    for(String part : parts) {
        System.out.println(part);
    }
```

Comment: I won't tell that "\\D+" is a regular expression if you don't tell ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
String input = "(xxx) xxx-xxxx"
String[] arrFirst = input.split(" ");
String[] arrSecond = arrFirst[1].split("-");

System.out.println(arrFirst[0] + " " +arrSecond[0] + "-" + arrSecond[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//By Benjamin Manford

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class tel {

  public static boolean validatePhone(String phone){
      //the range of numbers is between 9 and 10. you can make it any range you want
            return phone.matches("^[0-9]{9,10}$");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
            String phone = input.nextLine();
            while(validatePhone(phone) != true) {
                    System.out.print("Invalid PhoneNumber!");
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.print("Enter Phone Number: ");
                    phone = input.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("Correct telephone number");
            }


}
}
```